# Need android activity to wait until GPS location obtained

Tags: android, android-activity, gps, wait, android-location

Sorry for my english.
I'm trying to get a single location from GPS to put on global variables latitude, longitude.
GPS turns on, but the activity goes on before data is retrieved from GPS.

My needs in other words... method getCurrentLocation() must finish only if a location has been found and the longitude and latitude variables are filled, so I could use them in other method.
I know... user has to wait... I will solve this forward showing something on screen.
What should I do?
Thank you

I think I'm skipping stop listening GPS at some place. Where is better?

Code follows:

```
//Method to retrieve coordinates
public void getCurrentLocation() {
    //Use GPS if possible
    if(manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        //assign Listener to GPS
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
        Toast.makeText(this, LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){//toherwise, use NETWORK
        //assign Listener to NETWORK
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
        Toast.makeText(this, LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

//Class to store the location recived in two variables
final class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        //coordinates storing
        latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), latitude + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want android activity to wait until GPS location obtained, you might try to use `AsyncTask` for that. See [Android find GPS location once, show loading dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486055/android-find-gps-location-once-show-loading-dialog) for the answers. Basically in `onPreExecute` you can start dialog( it starts before the `doInBackground` is called). It means you are waiting till the time you can location and showing the dialog. Then in `doInBackground` you can get the location. After that finishes `onPostExecute` is called. You can stop is from inside `onPostExecute`. You can check if the location is not null and then call some other function from inside `onPostExecute` also if you want.

This might be one way. You can learn a basic example from [AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example) . You can also start by reading the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Some other similar helpful questions:

[Wait for current location - GPS - Android Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538389/wait-for-current-location-gps-android-dev)

[getting location instantly in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002630/getting-location-instantly-in-android)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Use LocusService 3rd party library!
[Goto LocusService](https://github.com/gligerglg/LocusService)

By invoking simple function you will able to get your current GPS or Net Location easily....

To solve your problem use this code!

```
LocusService locusService = new LocusService(this);
locusService.startRealtimeGPSListening(1000);   //Set intervel

locusService.setRealTimeLocationListener(new LocusService.RealtimeListenerService() {
        @Override
        public void OnRealLocationChanged(Location location) {
                if(location!=null){
                  //Do your Stuff here
                  finish();
                }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Be aware that this is just a simple wrapper of the android location listener.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue ,

Solved it, by using Activity life cycle methods.

---

1)GPS capturing function inside `onCreate(Bundle b)` method

2) intent or function which in need of GPS Location ,in `onStart()` method.

---

So Activity Start from `onCreate(bundle)` method where GPS location will be captured.Here
GPS Altitude,Latitude,Longitude values will be assigned to a global variables.

After that `onStart()` method will be executed ,in which GPS location global variables will called to do necessary action.

---

Hope this helped you

Answer (score 1):

Better to use getLastKnownLocation() method.
Here is an example of code:

Make your latitude and longitude as a global variable

```
double longitude;
double latitude;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedBundle) {
       super.onCreate(savedBundle);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_receipt_result);
       Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setElevation(0);

       locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

       if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    Activity#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
    }else{
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        Log.d("Location: ", "long-lat" + longitude + "-"+ latitude);
    }
}
```

After you can use the longitude and the latitude variable in the rest of your code.